# Filling and comparing char* inside a function

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I wrote the function `readChar()` which is designed to read the characters send by my WiFi module one by one(function works has advertised) and pass them to a char buffer of increasing size. The function should stop when `char *endChar` (multiple characters) have been detected or the number of character returned by `timedRead()` has exceeded `size_t length`.

I have several issues:

1/. I don't understand the syntax (found inside the Arduino Stream library) :

```
*buffer++ = (char)c;
```

Can you explain how the array `buffer` gets filled?
And why `buffer[index] = (char)c;` doesn't work here?

2/. I would like to compare `buffer` and `endChar` in the loop, possibly by using `strcmp(buffer,endChar)` (maybe there is a better way). But that doesn't seem to work. In fact when printing the ASCII values of my `char *buffer` then seem to increment from the end of the buffer. E.G.:
So what is the best way to do that comparison?

The code, inserted in the loop:

```
_dbgSerial->println("buffer");
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    _dbgSerial->print(buffer[i], DEC);
    _dbgSerial->print(",");
    }
_dbgSerial->println("");
```

prints:

> buffer
>
> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,10,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,10,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,10,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,10,0,0,0,
>   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,10,13,10,0,0,0,0,

Here is the function `readChar()`:

```
size_t Debugwifi::readChar(char *endChar, char *buffer, size_t length) {
if (length < 1) return 0;
size_t index = 0;
while (index < length) {
    int c = timedRead();
    if (c < 0 ) break;
    //buffer[index] = (char)c;
    *buffer++ = (char)c;
    _dbgSerial->println("buffer");
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        _dbgSerial->print(buffer[i], DEC);
        _dbgSerial->print(",");
    }
    _dbgSerial->println("");
    if (strcmp(buffer,endChar)==0) {
        break;
        _dbgSerial->println("brk");}
    index++;
    }
return index;
}
```

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? They are different languages and the right way to do this is completely different in the two languages. Also, `strcmp` is for comparing the contents of strings, not for checking if you've reached the end of a buffer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's C++ - This is a member function.

Comment: Ah, so why is this tagged C?

Comment: Because a lot of people think they are the same language.  vrieboss - please remove the C tag.

Comment: from what I understood from the arduino docs it is based upon c with c++ functionalities. but that's my poor understanding. don't hesitate to correct me/edit my post. same for `strcmp` I understood that null terminated char* are essentially strings and can be compared as such.

Comment: strcmp: Sort of, yes.  But buffer is is not a null terminated string.

Comment: What are the typical values that are passed in for endChar? If it is only 1 character the solution is much easier.

Comment: @MartinBonner it is declared when calling the function using `char buf[32] = {'\0'};` and `memset(buf,0,32);` then it's a matter of making sure length < 32 to have it always null terminated isn't it?

Comment: @Rickard no it's not 1character and that is why I am re-writing the function found in the arduino Stream library.

Comment: Then I'm guessing you want to compare the n last characters of what was read into buffer to your endChar. Right now your solution seems to want to compare everything that was read (even though it doesn't since buffer is increment, see answer below).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tagged C because char* (which this question is about) are sharing common implementation between c and c++. So both communities could be interested. The tag has been removed.

Comment: @vrleboss.  Right, if the memory is initialized to zero, then the array will be null terminated.  You would do better to move the memset into the function though - that way you can be *really* sure.  However, I will write an answer for you.

Comment: what's the difference between `*buffer++ = (char)c;` and `(*buffer)++ = (char)c;`?

Comment: (*buffer)++ says read the value of the address in buffer, then increment that value. (*buffer)++ = (char) c; is not valid since you are trying to assign a value to a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rickard has explained, `*buffer++ = (char)c;` is how you assign a character to the memory a pointer points at, and then increment the pointer.

However, your function has a lot of problems - you keep comparing unset memory with `*endChar`.  I suggest:

```
size_t Debugwifi::readChar(const char * const endStr, // const pointer to const.
                           char * const buffer, const size_t length) {
    if (length < 1) return 0;
    const size_t endLen = strlen(endStr);
    for (size_t index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        const int c = timedRead();
        if (c < 0 ) break;
        buffer[index] = (char)c;

        // Debug
        _dbgSerial->println("buffer");
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++){  // Better to use size_t here, 
                                              // and compare against length not 32
            _dbgSerial->print(buffer[i], DEC);
            _dbgSerial->print(",");
        }
        _dbgSerial->println("");

        // Finished?
        if (index >= endLen) {
            if (memcmp(&buffer[index-endLen], endStr, endLen)==0) {
                _dbgSerial->println("brk"); // Must do this *before* "break"!
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

I have added a lot of `const`s.  It's hard to have too many.

The important point is that once you have read enough characters, to start comparing the last characters you have read to the end marker.

Note that this function does not remove the end marker, and if you pass a 32-byte zero-filled array and it reads 32 characters, the result will *NOT* be zero terminated.

Finally, I changed the argument name to `endStr` because I had expected `endChar` to be a pointer to a single character - not a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: appreciate the detailed answer. `index` should be declared outside the for loop so it can be returned isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
*buffer++ = (char) c;
```

First writes the value of *c* to what *buffer* is currently pointing to.
Then it increments the *buffer*

This is also why your loop to print *buffer* doesn't work.
You start printing from the position after what was just filled.

This is also why your strcmp doesn't work. It doesn't actually compare what you have filled your buffer with. It compares the content beyond what have been filled.

If you want your printing code to work you should save the initial value of *buffer* before the loop;

const char *buffer_start = buffer;
Then use that in your printing code instead of buffer.

Comment: I understand - so `int i` shouldn't be initialized at `0` but the buffer was initial pointing to. How do you get that value or what is ???: `for (int i = ???`

Comment: I updated my answer. It is better to just save the initial value of buffer in another variable. Like const char *start = buffer;

Comment: I am not sure I can do `const char *buffer_start = buffer;` because `buffer` needs to get updated in the function and the updated value is used subsequently in my code.

Comment: Yes, but you only use start for the printing. buffer is still used in all the other places and will continue to work as before.
Having the address copied to another variable doesn't change how the original variable is used.